# How to access function inside PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop

What do I need to do to call $this->two() from inside my function innerOne? Is that possible with PHP OOP?

Here's the error I am recieving:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

Here's how my code looks:

```
class myClass  {

    function one(){

        function innerOne() {
            // Some code
            $this->two($var1, $var2);
        }

        // Some code

        innerOne();

    }

    function two($var1, $var2) {
    // Does magic with passed variables
        return $var1 . $var2;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function innerOne($t) {
  //some code...
  $t->two($var1, $var2);
}

innerOne($this);
```

Comment: Thanks man! I used your example and thought outside the box a bit and was able to solve it! Posted my solution in my original post if anyone wonders. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Absolutely, I couldn't accept it at the time i wrote the comment. "You'll have to wait 2 minutes before accepting this answer" is an awesome message to see - not everyday you get an answer so quickly. Bigups to Jacob!

Answer (score 2):

`innerOne` is actually a global function.

The fact you defined it inside a method does not matter, it's in global function table. See:

```
class myClass  {

    static function one(){

        function innerOne() {
            // Some code
            echo "buga!";
        }


    }
}

myClass::one();

innerOne();
```

gives "buga!". You have to call one() first so that the function is defined.

What you want is this:

```
class myClass  {

    function one($var1, $var2){
        return $this->innerOne($var1, $var2);
    }

    private function innerOne($var1, $var2) {
        return $this->two($var1, $var2);
    }

    function two($var1, $var2) {
    // Does magic with passed variables
        return $var1 . $var2;
    }


}

$var = new myClass();
echo $var->one("bu","ga");
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is only defined within that scope. So you can not access it outside of said scope. There are tricks around it but not any I'm going to recommend.

Comment: Not true. innerOne is a global function once it's defined.